# Appending records from one table to another (with different columns)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm looking for a way to add the records from one table to another effectively. The tables are similar, but different. Let's say I'm trying to append all of the data from Employee table B into Employee table A.

```
   Employee Table B
   ---------------
   EmpID (int), fname (text), lname(text)
   1            Bob           Dole
```

I want this data appended to

```
   Employee Table A
   empid (int)  fname(text)    lname(text)     DateOfBirth (DateTime)
```

as

```
   1             Bob           Dole              null / blank
```

I have to do this for around 30+ tables and am looking for a quick way to do it.

Rather than writing a `INSERT INTO table_a(empid, fname, lname) SELECT empid, fname,lname FROM table_b`, I would like to use some of Access's importing features to save time. I tried dumping each table to excel and appending to the necessary tables, but I got a `Subscript out of range error`. I also tried copy pasting the records to no avail.

Is there a tool that Access provides that will save me the trouble of writing an append query for each table?

Comment: I think an append query should do the trick; or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Where does Excel come into it? Do have tables in Excel that you wish to insert into Access or vice versa?

Comment: @Remou Nope, I was just curious as to using Excel as a medium for appending the tables (export to excel, import from excel). I tried that, but was getting a `subscript out of range` error. Due to foreign key constraints, I'm just going to have to manually do append queries for each table.

Comment: There is manually and manually. Loop through the tables and change the table name in the sql.

Comment: That's what the guy below suggested. I decided against it because I know it's just gonna yell at me about FK constraints.

Comment: This is a one off, yesno? Copy the sql to vba, copy the lines down, edit as appropriate, and run. Slow, but not as tedious as opening queries and changing them. Though I do not quite see why you feel something will moan about constraints in code but not on a query.

Comment: @Remou Somewhat one-off, I may have to do it 1-2 more times (TBD). I suppose if I use `dbFailOnError` with the vb code, it would tell me what I wanted to know as far as constraint violations.

Comment: Yes, and even DoCmd.RunSQL would be okay, because pressing Ok 30 times is just bearable. That way, you will even be able to make a note of the record count.

Answer (score 1):

Provided the field names are the same in both tables (except for the ones missing) you could write some code to do it for you. Use the `TableDefs` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb220949(v=office.12).aspx) object to loop through tables and look for "_a" tables to append to and create the INSERT statement on-the-fly by querying the TableDef's `.Fields` collection.

For example something like this should work (un-tested, written by hand!):

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim tdfLoop As TableDef
Dim strSql As String
Dim i as Integer
Dim strSourceTable as String
Dim strFieldList as String

Set dbs = CurrentDb

With dbs
  For Each tdfLoop In .TableDefs
     If Right(tdfLoop.Name, 2) = "_a" Then            
         strSourceTable = Mid(tdfLoop.Name, 1, Len(tdfLoop.Name)-2) & "_b"
         strSql = "INSERT INTO " & tdfLoop.Name & "("
         strFieldList = ""
         For i = 0 To tdfLoop.Fields.Count - 1
             strFieldList = strFieldList & tdfLoop.Fields(i).Name & ","
         Next i
         If strFieldList <> "" Then
             strFieldList = Mid(strFieldList, 1, Len(strFieldList) - 2)
         End If

         strSql = strSql & strFieldList & ") SELECT " & strFieldList & " FROM " & strSourceTable

         dbs.Execute(strSql)
     End If
  Next tdfLoop
End With

dbs.Close
Set dbs = Nothing
```

If the 'missing fields' do not have defaults defined in the table, then you could modify the above to return `NULL` values in their columns but I've assumed they have.

Comment: This isn't a bad idea, the only problem I would run into doing this would be with foreign key constraints. If I dropped all the foreign keys before doing this, and then reapplied them, it could work though.

Comment: Either that or define the order in which the tables are processed. You could define an array of table names, or use a temp table to hold the table names, and then loop through in that order. It would mean you have to manually key in the table names though.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking. Since I'm going to have to define the order regardless, I may just be better off doing append queries manually for each table. That way, I'll get the errors notifying me about constraint violations. Good thought though, in a perfect world, this would be the solution :)